# imageslider code in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript

i have done this code of imageslider in javascript that when click on an image its slides to show the next one , but the problem is i want this code to run with out global variables (only closure) but it is not working with me , any help? ( ps: i tried this code with closure but it doesn't work with me )

```js
var liEls = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
var index = 0;
var max = liEls.length - 1;

window.show = function(increase) {
  if (index == max) {
    index = -1;
  }

  index = index + increase;

  liEls[index].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });

  // console.log(index);

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: pink;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: 450px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Image Slide Show</h1>
<ul>
  <li><img class="img2" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-luxury-home-exterior-twilight-600w-639916900.jpg" onclick="show(+1)"></li>
  <li><img class="img3" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-luxury-home-exterior-twilight-600w-639916900.jpg" onclick="show(+1)"></li>
  <li><img class="img4" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-luxury-home-exterior-twilight-600w-639916900.jpg" onclick="show(+1)"></li>
  <li><img class="img2" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-luxury-home-exterior-twilight-600w-639916900.jpg" onclick="show(+1)"></li>
  <li><img class="img3" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-luxury-home-exterior-twilight-600w-639916900.jpg" onclick="show(+1)"></li>
  <li><img class="img4" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-luxury-home-exterior-twilight-600w-639916900.jpg" onclick="show(+1)"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you set index to 0 and in the next line you check if it's equal than max. that can't work. Also don't use onclick handler, use JS for this.

Comment: @cloned The check if is for multiples run, what he is trying to do. That is not the problem.

Comment: @Siba We don't have a working example which you describe without closures. This could be usefull. Now we lack too much information.

Comment: @Wimanicesir now i edited the code so its working good ,but i want it with out global variables for example using closure

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it without setting global variables. Only thing you have to do is to define which elements you want to click on, but that can also be put into a wrapper function if you'd like. Here is a [good example on how you could do it.](https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/concepts/) Even tough it's jQuery page, the first example doesn't use jQuery, it just shows you how you can wrap your code in your own function.

You would then have something like `myCarousel.init()` on page load.

```js
function scrollToNextElement(nextLI) {
 nextLI.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}

function scrollToFirstElement() {
  document.querySelector('.slideshow li').scrollIntoView({
   behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}


var lis = document.querySelectorAll('.slideshow li');
lis.forEach( li => {
 li.addEventListener('click', () => {
   li.nextElementSibling ? scrollToNextElement(li.nextElementSibling) : scrollToFirstElement();
 });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: pink;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Image Slide Show</h1>
<ul class="slideshow">
  <li><img class="img2" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-luxury-home-exterior-twilight-600w-639916900.jpg" ></li>
  <li><img class="img3" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-luxury-home-exterior-twilight-600w-639916900.jpg" ></li>
  <li><img class="img4" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-luxury-home-exterior-twilight-600w-639916900.jpg" ></li>
  <li><img class="img2" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-luxury-home-exterior-twilight-600w-639916900.jpg" ></li>
  <li><img class="img3" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-luxury-home-exterior-twilight-600w-639916900.jpg" ></li>
  <li><img class="img4" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-luxury-home-exterior-twilight-600w-639916900.jpg" ></li>
</ul>
```